# Django,No envia datos a la bd con ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, postgresql

Al presionar el boton de enviar del formulario. va al ***error function*** del archivo ***script.js***,
al mirar en consola "**POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 28518** , 
la base de datos es postgres. no esta guardando los datos, he revisado varias paginas por internet pero no encuentro la solución, solo quiero enviar los datos sin recargar la pagina ¿alguna idea?

**script.js**

```
var clContactForm = function() {

        /* local validation */
        $('#contactForm').validate({

            /* submit via ajax */
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                var sLoader = $('.submit-loader');

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: $(this).attr(''),
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function() { 

                        sLoader.slideDown("slow");

                    },
                    success: function(msg) {

                        // Message was sent
                        if (msg == 'OK') {
                            sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                            $('.message-warning').fadeOut();
                            $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                            $('.message-success').fadeIn();
                        }
                        // There was an error
                        else {
                            sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                            $('.message-warning').html(msg);
                            $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");
                        }

                    },
                    error: function() {
                        sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                        $('.message-warning').html("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
                        $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");

                    }

                });
            }

        });
    };
```

**formulario.html**

```
 <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" >

                    {% csrf_token %}


                    <fieldset>

                       {{form.nombre}}
                       {{form.email}}
                       {{form.telefono}}
                       {{form.mensaje}}


                        <div class="form-field">
                            <button class="full-width btn--primary">Submit</button>
                            <div class="submit-loader">
                                <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>
                                <div class="s-loader">
                                    <div class="bounce1"></div>
                                    <div class="bounce2"></div>
                                    <div class="bounce3"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**views.py**

```
def contacto(request):
    contactos = Contacto.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = ContactoForm(data=request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            formulario.save()
    else:
        formulario = ContactoForm()
    return render(request, 'formulario.html', {'contactos': contactos, 'form': formulario})
```

Comment: ¿Donde esta el archivo que llamas en la url del ajax? yo solo veo "$(this).attr('')" y no le has mandado ninguna dirección. si la tienes declarada en un elemento html debes decile cual $(this).attr('value') por ejemplo.

Comment: seria bueno que comentes como obtienes la url de ajax...url: $(this).attr(''),

Comment: El tema es que es una unica pagina y tiene varias secciones,
lo tenia asi **url: false** Tambien lo hice de este modo
**type: $(this).attr('method')**, el error esta en que no encuentra la ruta.  mi duda es ¿cual es la ruta para que se recargue?. si lo hago de esta forma.

Comment: lo que debes hacer es colocar en url de ajax tu url de urls.py de la views def contacto

Comment: es decir que si en tus urls.py definiste  url(r'^crear_contacto', contacto, name='crear_contacto'), ...en tu ajax deberiasponer : url: 'crear_contacto',..

Comment: esa url le dice a ajax que los datos que va enviar se dirijan hacia dicha url... por le metodo definido en tu caso post.. y asi en tu views.py lo recibiria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos te voy a colocar un ejemplo:

suponiendo tengo el siguiente formulario html:

```
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm">
 {% csrf_token %}
{{form.nombre}}
{{form.email}}
{{form.telefono}}
{{form.mensaje}}

<button class="full-width btn--primary" onclick="grabarDatos();">Grabar Datos</button>
</form>
```

si te fijas en el button he agregado el evento onclick que invoca una funcion llamada **grabarDatos** esta funcion es de JavaScript:

```
    <script>
    function getCookie(name) {

      var cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
              // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      //RETORNANDO EL TOKEN
      return cookieValue;

  }//end function getCookie

    function grabarDatos(){
     var nombre = $("#id_nombre").val();
     if(nombre =="" || nombre == null){
     alert("ingrese un nombre");
     return false;
     }
     var email = $("#id_email").val();
     if(email =="" || email == null){
     alert("ingrese un correo");
     return false;
     }
     var telefono = $("#id_telefono").val();
     if(telefono =="" || telefono == null){
     alert("ingrese un telefono");
     return false;
     }
     var mensaje = $("#id_mensaje").val();
     if(mensaje =="" || mensaje == null){
     alert("ingrese un mensaje");
     return false;
     }

    //envio por ajax
    //token
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "crear_contacto",
        data:{
        csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken, 
        nombre:nombre,
        email:email,
        telefono:telefono,
        mensaje:mensaje,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        codigo = data.resultado;
        if(codigo=='ok_insert'){
          alert("Datos Grabados con exito !!");
        }
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

            alert('Error al intentar Conectarse: Verifique su conexion a Internet.');

        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

            alert('La Pagina solicitada no fue encontrada [404]');

        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

            alert('Erro Interno [500]');

        } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

            alert('Error en el retorno de Datos. [parseJson]');

        } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

            alert('Tiempo de Espera agotado');

        } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {
            alert('Solicitud Abortada. [Ajax Request]');

        } else {
            alert('Error desconocido: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }//end if 

        }//end error
    }); 
    }//end function grabarDatos
    </script>
```

como te fijas armo los datos en variables como nombre, email, telefono, mensaje para posteriormente ser enviados por ajax.
ahora tu **views.py**:

```
def CrearContacto(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
      nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
      email = request.POST.get('email')
      telefono = request.POST.get('telefono')
      mensaje = request.POST.get('mensaje')
      #insertando la data
      contacto = Contacto(
      nombre = nombre,
      email = email,
      telefono = telefono,
      mensaje = mensaje,
      )
      contacto.save()
      data ={
    'resultado':'ok_insert'
      }
      return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

ahora algo muy importante para ajax es la url que es por donde va enviar la data, la cual se define en tus urls.py:

```
from myapp.views import CrearContacto
urlpatterns = [
  ......
  ......
  url(r'^crear_contacto', CrearContacto, name='crear_contacto')
]
```

Listo con esto ya estaria basicamente todo tu ajax, algo muy importante que debes incluir para ajax es el token caso contrario te generara error.

[Token Django Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/)

Espero te sirva y suerte !!

Answer (score 1):

Integrarlo en alguna carpeta static de tu proyecto Hacer referencia al script en tu plantilla html de la siguiente manera: ​ Listo! Ahora puedes hacer tus peticiones sin tener que preocuparte en el token :)

```
  /**
     * Este script de javascript permite trabajar transparentemente solicitudes que requieren 
     * protección del token CSRF por medio de AJAX JQUERY.
     * Esto te permitirá hacer solcitudes a web Services de Django por medio de AJAX Jquery.
     * Para utilizarlo basta con integrar el archivo DjangoAjax.js en tu directorio de JS  y hacer referencia a él en tus templates 
     * que requieren del uso de AJAX por POST o algún otro que requiera el token CSRF.
     * Este script está basado en la documentación oficial de Django https://docs.djangoproject.com
     */

    $(function(){
        //Obtenemos la información de csfrtoken que se almacena por cookies en el cliente
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        //Agregamos en la configuración de la funcion $.ajax de Jquery lo siguiente:
        $.ajaxSetup({
                        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
                                // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
                                // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
                                // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                            }
                        }
        });

    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }

    // usando jQuery
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }


        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // estos métodos no requieren CSRF
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
    });
```

El ejemplo de consulta seria

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mi_url',
    type: "POST",
    data: {'variable': value},
    success: function (response) {
       //lo que haces si es exitoso
    }

});
```

Y tu archivo para que sea solo por consultas ajax para una api-rest

```
def ajax_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "This is ajax"
    else:
        message = "Not ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```